# always failed to create a document when it has a Firestore Geopoint field when using Firebase rules unit testing library

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am tryin to perform testing to my security rules using [@firebase/rules-unit-testing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/rules-unit-testing) library using emulators

I have an Event class like this

```
class Event {

  title: string 
  coordinate: FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint

}
```

create an instance

```
const event = new Event("event title", new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(-6.931980, 107.559540))
```

and then I write testing for my security rules like this using Mocha

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";

function getFirestore(auth?: TokenOptions) {
    return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: projectID, auth: auth}).firestore();
}

it("should create an event document", async () => {

     const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
     const ref = db.collection("events").doc("myEvent");
     const event = new Event("event title", new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(-6.931980, 107.559540))
     const eventData = { ...event};
      
     const promise = ref.set(eventData);
     await firebase.assertSucceeds(promise);
});
```

but I have error

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid
> data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field
> coordinate in document events/myEvent)

the error said that the coordinate property using custom object (i.e FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint)

but I need to test my security rules. I have rules like this

```
request.resource.data.coordinate is latlng
```

so how do I test if a field is latlng or not but, I can't create a document which is a Firestore Geopoint?

is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from [thebrianchen in here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4723#issuecomment-814324864)

> The issue here is that the web and admin SDKs have separate GeoPoint
> classes that are not interoperable with each other. If you're using
> the web SDK with initializeTestApp(), you'll have to the GeoPoint
> class from the web SDK. In your case, you'll need to use the web SDK's
> GeoPoint class:

so I have to change the way I create GeoPoint data. From

```
new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(-6.931980, 107.559540)
```

to be

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";

new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(-6.931980, 107.559540)
```